# WCF and Delphi - Should I use bytes[] or string?

Tags: c#, wcf, delphi, unicode

I have created an WCF application that will be consumed by a Delphi 7 class. AFAIK, C# `string` type is `UTF16` and Delphi's 7 `string` type is `Ansi`.

The question is: because of C# and Delphi string types are different, should I declare all my functions with `bytes[]` instead of `string`? Am I gonna have issues by using `strings` on my methods?

Comment: Delphi 7 also offers `WideString`, which is equivalent to the Windows `BSTR` type.

Comment: Maybe the importer knows what it's doing, then. Does your program work? My comment was mainly aimed at the C# people who'll be answering this question, to remind them what's available in Delphi.

Comment: Yes up until Delphi 2007 (I think) the aliais string was AnsiString, but Delphi (since Delphi 2) has a WideString for 16 bit chars, however I do not believe it specifies the encoding used in a WideString.

Comment: @pete WideString is a wrapper around COM BSTR and so is UTF-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think youll need to decalre everything WideString in Delphi.

*You say you made the .NET WCF services and there to be consumed by Delphi 7 clients, but are the clients also under your control? your question seems to imply that is the case. I answer assuming that to be true.*

Even if your [OperationContract]s in .NET side have byte[] type parameters all of the default contract wire serialisers (SOAP, JASON, etc...) will use the .NET XML formatting and this is (AFAK) all UTF-16.

So whilst you could put your parameters into explicit byte arrays the message payloads would all be UTF-16 XML.